# Cannot send GPS Location to server

Tags: android, eclipse, gps

I am trying to send the GPS location from the Device to a server.
But the problem that im faceing is that the Location is not sending to my Server.

My code looks like this;

```
//###################################################################################################################      
   public void postData(String la, String lo) {                                                               //#
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();                                                       //#
       HttpGet htget = new HttpGet("http://My server IP/GPS/"+la+"/"+lo);                                     //#
                                                                                                              //#
      try {                                                         /*##################################*/    //#
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);         /* send it to my server............ */    //#
            String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();      /*##################################*/    //#
            Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();                                                          //#
                                                                                                              //#
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {                                                                     //#
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error #1", 5000).show();        //#
    } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                 //#
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error #2", 5000).show();        //#
    }                                                                                                         //#
}                                                                                                             //#
```

i am not using port number because the file will come near my webserver files. (with has default 80 as port number.)
My webserver is reachable so i belive the folder called ''GPS'' must be reachable too.
i gave permission as RWX.

i also added the following codes in my xml file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

but no luck when i run it...
any help?

pic of the server side : [image: serverside....]

the Source where i got the codes is : [here](http://www.gideondsouza.com/blog/how-to-get-the-current-location-address-and-send-it-to-a-server-on-android#.Uoe_3eKp75x)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:gps]? Do you believe your problem is constrained to gps data and other data would send just fine? I.e., do you suspect that the issue you're having is in any remote way related to gps beyond that you happen to be using gps data?

Answer (score 0):

//This is working fine for me ....hope it willl help you too

```
String url ="url of your web serive ";
Log.d("url to update location", url);
String response = HttpRequest.getDataFromServices(url);
    try {
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
if (jobj.getString("success").equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "true")) {

                            Log.d("updated", "Location udated");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("updated", "Location not udated");
                            Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                                    "Unable to update Location",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```